# Use zsh if possible, bash if not

Tags: linux, shell

I have a couple of ubuntu machines and my home folder is shared across all of them. I think there is another computer, which holds the folder and it is mounted as I log in, not sure tough, I didn't configure them and I cannot change the config. On part of them, there is `zsh` installed, on other not. By default, my shell is `bash`. I also don't have any `sudo` access and cannot use `chsh` command. Is there a way, to setup my user, so that it launches `zsh` if possible and uses `.zshrc` and `bash` if `zsh` is not installed on the machine? I've seen the thread, on how to change the default shell to another one without `chsh` by modifying `.profile` file, but I don't know how to adapt it to that situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following to the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
command -v zsh && exec zsh
```

If zsh is in your PATH then it will start an interactive zsh shell and read ~/.zshrc

Comment: It would be better if you didn't keep `bash` waiting for `zsh` by using `command -v zsh && exec zsh`.

Comment: Adding it to `.bashrc` didn't work, but when it is in `.profile` it works fine. I still have to find out, why exactly I had to do it this way, but for now I have it working, which is nice.